# How to boot from CD using GRUB?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, windows, bootloader, boot-order

so I have this dualboot config in my pc with ubuntu precise and win 7 running alongside. I need to reinstall win 7 since its acting a bit strange lately; but during bios my keystrokes are not recognized for some reason. Since I can't change the boot order this way, my only option is grub to boot into the win setup.

Any ideas on how though? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i can remember, if you already have win7 you can install easyBCD and from there, you can change the boot order. 
dont forget, if you reinstall windows, install easyBCD to reinstall the grub and have acces to ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different boot devices behind CD (CD player and/or burner) and GRUB (Hard Drive Disk). So booting from CD using GRUB is not possible.

Comment: great, so what to do if boot order is not able to change?

Comment: You can boot an ISO file as a loop device however from grub2